# Best File To Store System-Wide Environmental Variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, export

Where is the best location that will work with the most flavors of Linux (Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora, Etc) to store system wide `environmental variables`?

Seems like all three of these locations will work. Which is the best?

```
/etc/environment
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are these environemntal variables for use by a user in a shell or by some application?

Answer (score 2):

That's just what files like `/etc/profile` are for. :)

Comment: No, that's not what `/etc/profile` is for. It's not meant to be edited. Instead one should create new file in `/etc/profile.d`. See [What do the scripts in /etc/profile.d do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64258/5355)